# Shape keys deforming mesh during image render

Tags: shape-keys

I have an issue where I edit my mesh, insert key frames,and save the file, but whenever I close Blender and reopen the file or try to render a still image the armature gets completely distorted even though it has been saved. I think the shape keys are the problem, even though they are set to zero. What do I do?

Comment: Does the problem persist, if you save your file as a new file and remove the shapekeys? What do you mean with *the **armature** gets distorted*? Armatures usually don't render, only geometry does.

Comment: attach file? http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/